# javascript animate dosnt loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a roulette game that looks like this:[image]

I want it to slow down more and more the further it goes, so i have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var moveTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 2000
    var slowDown = 1000;
    while (moveTime > 0) {
      $("div").animate({
        left: slowDown + "px"
      });

      if (slowDown > 0) {
        slowDown--;
        moveTime = 0;
      }
      slowDown--;
      moveTime--;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -8400px;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 100px, #000000 100px, #000000 200px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div></div>
```

But the problemis that it only play the animation 1 time. I have also tried with a infinityloop but that dont work either, same with pressing the button twice nothing happend the second time.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us some of your HTML so we can replicate the whole thing?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AxZL3PmD

Comment: `if (slowDown > 0) {` is always true the first time through so 2nd time `while (moveTime > 0) {` is false. So only 1 loop iteration. You might consider using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` instead of this loop.

Comment: main problem is that $.animate() is gonna run asynchronosly - meaning the code after it will continue running before the .animate method is done. and in your case the slowDown is bigger than 0, moveTime is set to 0 and that ends your while loop - and animate is only called once.
you could chain it (or put them to queue) or just call the next animation when the previous is done (using the .done() promise)
[link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that on successive clicks the `div` element is already at the `left` position you're trying to animate it to, so nothing appears to happen.

To fix this, reset the `left` position back to `0` before you run the animation again. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var moveTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 2000
    var slowDown = 1000;
    var $div = $('div').css('left', 0); // < reset the position here

    while (moveTime > 0) {
      $div.animate({
        left: slowDown + "px"
      });

      if (slowDown > 0) {
        slowDown--;
        moveTime = 0;
      }
      
      slowDown--;
      moveTime--;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -8400px;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 100px, #000000 100px, #000000 200px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure if I understood well and if Rory did actually give you the answer you were expecting, but here is what I suggest.

If you want to get a roulette-like animation, you can use jQuery's `animate` with customized easing functions provided here : [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

You can get rid of your `while` loop and only use `animate` jQuery function instead, along with the **Easing Plugin**.

Here is what it looks like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    
    // Play with these two values
    var nSpin = 4;
    var slow = 2;

    $("div")
      .stop()
      .css({ left: 0 })
      .animate({
        left: nSpin * 1000
      }, slow * nSpin * 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
    
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 -8400px;
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 100px, #000000 100px, #000000 200px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<button>Start Animation</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I got it t work with the solution from Rory but this example was better i woud say. Buy less code is always better